# How can I make my plugin automatically install third party features?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am developing an eclipse feature that has a dependency on Acceleo. When I install my feature using its update site I get an error because it cannot find plugins related to Acceleo.

My feature manifest declares dependant plugins and features.

My feature installs fine if the user adds the Acceleo update site before installing my feature or installs Acceleo before installing my feature but I would like this  to happen automatically.

Is this even possible?

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P2 supports referring other repositories in its metadata. It looks like below,

```
<references size='2'>
<repository uri='http://www.example.com/eclipse/updates' url='http://www.example.com/eclipse/updates' type='0' options='0'/>
<repository uri='http://www.example.com/eclipse/updates' url='http://www.example.com/eclipse/updates' type='1' options='0'/>
</references>
```

You can add update site reference of Acceleo to a feature.xml file. This will be converted into a repository reference by the p2 publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Your `site.xml` can reference another file that lists additional update sites to use for finding required dependencies. See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/597390/ for some tips.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work anymore link here http://www.robotoworks.com/mechanoid/update/site.xml It still fails to find acceleo plugins :(